# Cloning a private repo is taking forever. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: git, github, git-bash, github-desktop

GitHub Desktop - Cloning a private repo is taking forever. Am I doing something wrong?

So when logged into GitHub, I'm looking at my private repo. So I click "Clone Repo" and open it in desktop. Then I choose where I want to clone it to, and now the little arrows in the upper left hand corner have just been spinning for like 10 minutes now.

Any idea why this is taking so long? Or am I doing something wrong? I'm logged into the account both on GitHub and GitHub Desktop that has access to this private repo. Is there something else that I should do? I'm not using command line, just using the GUI that GitHub Desktop has.

The repo is only about 120MB and my connection is 300 Mbps down / 20 Mbps up. doubt it's either. I am a Read Only user to the repo, though. Do read only users not have clone permissions?

This is an image of what I've been looking at. Nothing happening, no error messages, nothing. https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DaDq.png Just those two arrows going around and around.

---

Did a clone via Git Bash just now, and that worked fantastically. Not sure what the big difference is. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked progress in the actual file system?

Comment: @isherwood Do you mean looking in the folder and seeing if the files are being cloned? I did just now at your request, and I see that even the folder hasn't been created for the repo that's being cloned yet. That seems pretty odd, right?

Comment: Yeah, something's awry, then. You should see files coming in immediately.

Comment: @isherwood I just tried command line via git bash and that worked fantastically. I wonder what the big difference is. That's very odd.

Comment: It's hard for us to say, not knowing anything about your software setup. You might just try a reinstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what happened now. I was using GitHub Desktop's new *Beta* version on their site, instead of the old, stable, version.

I'm using the stable version instead of the beta version and it works great.

Thank you everyone for your time and assistance.